# How to disable sorting on columns when no records are available in kendo ui grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am using Kendo ui grid:http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index

I am doing server side sorting now what i want is when "**no records are available**" then i want to disable sorting on some column.

So how to do it??

Note:I am using Script for kendo ui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can not set enable/disable sorting at run time in kendo Grid but we can indirectly achieve this thing by using below code snippet.

```
<body>
    <div id="grid"></div>
    <script src="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/content/shared/js/products.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //To test your requirement please remove comment from below code line
            //products = null;
            $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: {
                    data: products,
                    schema: {
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                ProductName: { type: "string" },
                                UnitPrice: { type: "number" },
                                UnitsInStock: { type: "number" },
                                Discontinued: { type: "boolean" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                height: 550,
                groupable: true,
                sortable: true,
                columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" }
                ]
            });
            $("#grid .k-grid-header .k-link").click(function (e) { 
                if ($("#grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data().length == 0) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Let me know if any concern.

Comment: Thank you so much for your ans but i am having 2 grid.i am having records in my 1st grid and no records in my 2nd grid.so my sorting is not working now for my 1st grid using your code

Comment: You rocked man.Thank you thank you so much.now same click event for page size change?